# How to avoid conflict between AutoSave and Manual Save functionality

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an AutoSave functionality which triggers every minute.
I am initiating this auto save from an ajax call to a common method in c#, which is also getting used by Manual Save functionality.

My issue is, when i Save a record[From Save button] and if auto save functionality triggers [and in vise a versa case], it saves the records 2 times in stead of saving it 1 time only.

Is there any way in MVC 5 or javascript where i can avoid this conflict?

Comment: I can't come up with something else than having a 'isSaving' state on the client, which is checked before the saving (either manual or automaticly) starts. Is it bad however when the save is executed twice? I can guess it's a problem for a new record, but updates aren't bad I guess if they happen twice at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the fact if a save is currently underway. A boolean saving state should do the trick. You could also make an enum if you want to have more saving states, to keep track of what is going on (SAVE_COMPILING_INFO, SAVE_PUTTING_ON_DISC, SAVE_IDLE, etc.)

```
bool isCurrentlySaved=false;
```

and then, whether for manual saving or autosaving

```
if(!isCurrentlySaved)
{
   isCurrentlySaved=true;
   savestuff();
}
```

**Make sure that, when the save process is completed (whether it failed or succeeded) that the variable is set back to false. Otherwise, if the saving process was cut off, it will remain true and you will not be able to do another save call at a later time.**